# Graphical Binary Search Tree - Node Spacing

Tags: java, swing, graphics, binary-tree

I'm having difficulty calculating the spacing between nodes in a binary search tree for my assignment. I have the GUI implemented where I can manually create a tree or create it by importing a text file as well as other features etc.

In the binary search tree node class there are getter and setter methods for X and Y coordinates that I am supposed to use. Now, I have got it working, but this is a mash up of code I found dotted around the internet. See [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vjlY.png), for example.

The thing is, I do **not** want to use this code because

1. It's not mine and,
2. It does't make use of the getter and setter methods provided.

I have been told that in order to get the spacing right:

*X co-ordinate is proportional to the order number in which the node is processed in the course of an in-order traversal.*

*Y co-ordinate is related to the depth of the node.*

I have a `getHeight()` method, which works and I assume is the same as getting the depth.

I hope someone can help me or point me in the right direction.

**UPDATE**

For the Y co-ordinates?

```
int index = -1;
BinaryTreeNode nodes[];
int[] levels;

public void build(BinaryTreeNode node, int level)
{
    if (node != null)
    {
        build(node.getLeftNode(), level+1);
        index++;
        nodes[index] = node;
        levels[index] = level;
        build(node.getRightNode(), level+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd love to help but what is the question? How do you get the in-order traversal count?

Comment: The question is, how to calculate the node spacing when creating and displaying a binary search tree in a GUI. I suppose I did ramble a bit in my question :)

Answer (score 0):

For the Y coordinate, iterate up through the parents and sum up the height of each parent node. For each parent, add some white spacing also, i.e.

```
int y = 0;
Parent parent = child.getParent();
while(parent != null) {
   y += 10; // spacing
   y += parent.getHeight();

   parent = parent.getParent(); // next iteration
}
```

However this is not a very practical approach. Rather, you should iterate level for level - start with the top node, then the first two children and then the 4 grandchildren and so on. For example: Add the top node to a list, traverse the list and create a new list for all their children, then set the new list to the old, and continue in a while loop till the list is empty.

Now for the x-position, it is more tricky, as a nice layout depends on the number of nodes at that particular level. If the node three always is binary and balanced, there are 2 to the power of n nodes per level. If not, you must first check out how many nodes there are per level. When done, just divide the screen width by the number of nodes and place them in order, adding to the x coordinate as you go.

EDIT:
I prefer this approach:

```
class BinaryTreeNode {

    BinaryTreeNode left;
    BinaryTreeNode right;

    int x;
    int y;
}

public void position(BinaryTreeNode root, int nodeHeight, int nodeWidth, int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {

    List<BinaryTreeNode> nodes = new ArrayList<BinaryTreeNode>();

    nodes.add(root);

    int level = 0;
    while(!nodes.isEmpty()) {

        // we know now the number of nodes and the level
        int y = level * nodeHeight;

        // the x position depends on the number of nodes:
        int widthPerNode = screenWidth / nodes.size();

        int x = 0; // start at leftmost

        // now have (fixed) y position and starting point for x (leftmost)
        for(BinaryTreeNode node : nodes) { // for loop iterates in-order
            node.y = y;
            node.x = x; // TODO: center node within available space

            x += widthPerNode;
        }

        // this level is complete, store all children in a list
        List<BinaryTreeNode> childNodes = new ArrayList<BinaryTreeNode>();
        for(BinaryTreeNode node : nodes) { // for loop iterates in-order
            if(node.left != null) {
                childNodes.add(node.left);
            }
            if(node.right != null) {
                childNodes.add(node.right);
            }
        }

        // continue to next level using the collected children as the new parents
        nodes = childNodes;

        level++;
    }

    // TODO: insert insets between nodes
    // TODO: insert stop criteria for y outside screen
    // TODO: insert stop criteria for x outside screen
    // TODO: getters and setters

}
```

Also, you can modify this method to return to you the nodes whom need to be drawn, if this is not already within your paint() method.

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas for the help. I need to let what you said sink in for a bit :).. I'll post an update if/when I get my eureka moment...thanks

Comment: if you find y level by level first, x will be straightforward

Comment: Feel free to ask if too difficult, but then the code will not be as much your own.. :P

Comment: Didn't get my eureka moment :(...but still trying....dont want to give in yet :P....It is very difficult lol

Comment: try a while loop with a for loop inside..?

Comment: For the Y co-ordinates, could I have an array of nodes and an array of ints for the levels, then recursively build the tree? From my lab work today We were given the piece of code that I posted above...what do you think?

Comment: the lab code is fair, but I don't love it, still you should do what you find the most appealing. Also, array[]s will not work of course. Recursive algorithms can look easy but be hard.

Comment: Excuse the late reply....I put your method into a class that extends my binary search tree class (am not alowed to modify these). In my insertButton event listener, i am calling your method and sending as parameters, rootNode, width & height of node to be drawn and the Width and Height for the screen size. Your TODO comments, is the insert insets the lines between the nodes?, not sure what you mean by that. Anyway, once I had it implemented, nothing happened except the display of the root node in the top left corner. I tryed tracing through it on paper but just cant figure this damn thing out.

Answer (score 0):

Y-axis is easy. spread the levels 100 pixels out and you're done.

X-axis is trickier.

Suppose you have 1 node (leaf node). It needs say 40 pixels (cause 40 pixels is the size of the circle)

Suppose you have a node with two leaf children. The total width = 40 * 2 + SPACING. (say SPACING = 20) = 100.

Suppose you have a third-level node. each of the children is 100 pixels, so 100 * 2 + SPACING = 220.

4th-level node: 220 * 2 + 20 = 460.

nth-level node: 40 * 2^(n-1) + (2^(n-1) - 1) * 20 = SIZE * 2^(n-1) + SPACING * (2^(n-1) - 1)

Comment: Hi iluxa...sorry for the lack of response, am still no furthur with regards to the spacing. Thanks for the help and response though :)..Not giving up though